# Angular ng-repeat not repeating tr

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here. For some reason angular will build out the div structure 10 times because there are 10 items in $scope.aggregators. However it doesn't build out the TR structure at all?

```
<div class="info-pane" ng-controller="CatalogCtrl">

<table id="records">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span>Vendor Code</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="aggregator in aggregators}">
            <td>{{aggregator.vendor_code}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div ng-repeat="aggregator in aggregators">

</div>
```

Comment: remove `}` from `ng-repeat="aggregator in aggregators}"`

Comment: You have "}" in your ng-repeat. try removing it
<tr ng-repeat="aggregator in aggregators">
            <td>{{aggregator.vendor_code}}</td>
        </tr>

Comment: you have an extra } in the tr ng-repeat

Comment: Well now I just feel like an idiot. Thank you everyone.

Comment: There is a curly brace in your ng-repeat

Answer (score 1):

> remove } from ng-repeat="aggregator in aggregators}"